# Регулярное выражение для проверки отсутствия пробелов в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Совсем умаялся...
Нужна регулярка, которая бы при наличии пробела в строке возвращала `false`.

С регуляркой, которая бы возвращала `true` проблем нет. А вот с `false` ничего не получается.
и так пробовал `/[\s]{0}/ig` и так `/[^\\s]+/ig` и еще кучу вариантов... абсолютно не получается - все время `true` выводит.

Comment: `if /\s/.test(string) { return false; }` - это?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, находчиво, но мне нужно,. чтобы само регулярное выражение возвращало `false`, а не функция

Comment: `/^\S*$/` или `/^\S+$/` - так? Вам это где надо использовать? Может, `pattern="\S*"`? ``pattern="\S+"``? Приведите ваш код.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, первый и второй варианты работают как и задумано. Спасибо. Оформляйте, как ответ. .... а кода, собственно нет... просто в существующую логику валидации (где уже есть десяток других паттернов), нужно добавить еще этот

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для проверки на отсутствие пробельных символов в строке можно использовать

```
/^\S*$/
```

или

```
/^\S+$/
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\S*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от пробельных (если использовать `+` вместо `*`, 1 и более таких символов, т.е. не найдётся пустая строка)
- `$` - конец строки.